# Can a dead motherboard battery cause USB errors

Tags: usb, motherboard

Recently I have been experiencing a slew of USB related errors such as my mouse and headphones (both razer) randomly disconnecting and reconnecting. Today when starting my computer I got a CMOS error and needed to select the drive to boot from so I concluded that my motherboard battery has died. So could this have been causing my USB errors or do I need to look in another place?

Comment: Unlikely. The CMOS battery just keeps the CMOS/BIOS alive with your boot info. Maybe you have a short somewhere on the motherboard, which is a) draining the CMOS battery and b) disrupting your USB connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering USB is part of the MB hardware, it is possible the BIOS has become corrupted and causing issues.

I would suggest these two things;

- Change the CMOS battery to ensure it is not the issue
- Flash the latest BIOS update

Answer (score 0):

I had a PC running without working battery for several months and didn't notice any USB related issues. Moreover it's impossible since USB is powered by PSU and CMOS is powered by separate power line directly from battery.

Here are some possible causes:

- **(Most likely)** Resetting CMOS caused some settings to reset to their defaults (which might be changed in FW upgrade)
- A coincidence with actual hardware or software problem. Try to change ports, get rid of USB hub, check logs for errors.